# Store data from 2D array to an Array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

First of all, I store the data into a 2D array and the code is working fine. 
The code is shown as below,

```
  for(int a = 0; a < bitmap1.getWidth(); a++){
      // ------ This is X
                        for(int b = 0; b < bitmap1.getHeight()-1; b++){
                            // ---------- This is Y
                            intArray1[a][b] = Integer.toHexString(bitmap1.getPixel(a,b));
                            intArray2[a][b] = Integer.toHexString(bitmap2.getPixel(a,b));
                            intArray3[a][b] = Integer.toHexString(bitmap3.getPixel(a,b));
                            intArray4[a][b] = Integer.toHexString(bitmap4.getPixel(a,b));
                            intArray5[a][b] = Integer.toHexString(bitmap5.getPixel(a,b));
                            intArray6[a][b] = Integer.toHexString(bitmap6.getPixel(a,b));
                            intArray7[a][b] = Integer.toHexString(bitmap7.getPixel(a,b));
                            intArray8[a][b] = Integer.toHexString(bitmap8.getPixel(a,b));
                        }
                    }//end of Nested FOR
```

Then i use `nested for loops` to change the data from the `arrays` as above. However, this is just the `1st array` from my `8 array`. Is there any others way to reduce so much duplicated code instead of copying the same code as shown in below and do the convert from the `1st array` to `8 array` ?

```
    int [][] arrayOneZero = new int [array1.length][array1.length];
    for(int a = 0; a < array1.length; a++){
        for(int b = 0; b < array1.length-1; b++){
            if(array1[a][b].equals("ffffffff")){
                //This is White
                arrayOneZero[a][b] = 1;
            }else if(array1[a][b].equals("ff000000")){
                //This is Black
                arrayOneZero[a][b] = 0;
            }else if(array1[a][b].equals("00000000")){
                //THis is Black
                arrayOneZero[a][b] = 0;
            }
        }
```

After that, I want to get the data from the method and the result is all 0, since i pretty sure the result will be 1 or 0. But I dont know how to write the data from 2D array to an Array since the code shown below is definitely wrong.

```
 int [][] arrayReturned1 = getArrayText(intArray1);
 int [] colorValue = new int[bitmap1.getWidth()*bitmap1.getHeight()];
      for(int a = 0; a < bitmap1.getWidth(); a++) {
            for(int b = 0; b < bitmap1.getHeight()-1; b++) {
                   arrayReturned1[a][b] = colorValue[a];
             }
      }
```

### Question is edited, but the issue is still remain.

Comment: `arrayReturned1[a][b] = colorValue[a];` - don't you mean `colorValue[index] = arrayReturned1[a][b];`?  Note that I used `index` here because I assume you want to convert the 2D array to a 1D array. In that case the length of the array would be `width * height` and `index` would either be `a * height` or `b * width` depending on whether you want the data stored column-by-column or row-by-row (which would be the more common way).

Comment: Also note that in `getArrayText()` the only condition that has any effect would be `array1[a][b].equals("ffffffff")` (btw I'd use `equalsIgnoreCase(...)`) - all others wouldn't do anything because the array elements are already initialized to 0. Additionally your comments are a little misleading - normally 1 represents white and 0 black (and `ffffffff` would represent white with full opacity while `ff000000` could represent black with full opacity when ARGB is used or red with zero opacity when RGBA is used).

Comment: @Thomas since i get the array from the method, for example, `arrayReturned1[0][0]` the value is 1, then i want the value 1 to add into the array `colorValue[0]`. Somethings like this, and it going to nested loops since the `arrayReturned1[a][b]` is 2D array..

Comment: @Thomas btw, thanks for responding.. for ARGB, `#ffffffff` is representing black and black is 1. Am I wrong here ?

Comment: As I said, if you want to "add" the value of  `arrayReturned1[0][0]` to `colorValue` you need to call `colorValue[0] = arrayReturned1[0][0];`. I'm also not sure you understood or agree with the other part of my first comment: if `arrayReturned1` has the dimensions `5x3` you have 15 elements (5 inner arrays with 3 elements each) so `colorValue` should probably have a length of 15 and not 5 like in your code (`int [] colorValue = new int[bitmap1.getWidth()];`).

Comment: Also note that `for(int b = 0; b < array1.length-1; b++)` would not work if `arrayReturned1` had dimensions like 5x3 because in that case you'd get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Instead you'll want to use ` b < arrayReturned1[a].length`. - If you're unsure about the why then you'd probably revisit a tutorial on multidimensional arrays.

Comment: Finally, in ARGB you'd split `#ffffffff` into 4 components which each have the integer value of 255 (that's FF in hex). Having a value of 255 for R(ed), G(reen) and B(lue) means white (full intensity for each channel) - black almost always is 0. As for the A(lpha) channel the interpretation of the value would depend on how that channel is used but in almost all cases a value of 255 would mean the color is fully opaque (and `ffffffff` would mean white). A value of A = 0 would mean the color is not visible at all so it wouldn't matter at all (and could be considered black in your case).

Comment: @Thomas thanks for correcting my misunderstanding on the ARGB concept, a big thanks from me.. let me edit my program and have another try

Comment: @Thomas however, the problems from me is still here, the result is still getting the same which is all 0. I dont know what is the problem occurs here. Or maybe i should change to another method to declare ?

Comment: I hope you didn't just read up on the ARGB concept but also on the rest I commented on. If you did and adjusted your code accordingly then please update your question with your current code and also include how you check the data.

Comment: i found that the method `getArrayText()` return all in 0 and i fixed it by implement it without using the method. I was implement the nested for loops in my main method and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I find myself a solution where I use the `arrayList` to store the data. And it works fine.

```
 ArrayList<String>arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(int a = 0; a < bitmap1.getWidth(); a++){
                        for(int b = 0; b < bitmap1.getHeight(); b++){
                            String a1 = String.valueOf(arrayInput1[a][b]);
                            String a2 = String.valueOf(arrayInput2[a][b]);
                            String a3 = String.valueOf(arrayInput3[a][b]);
                            String a4 = String.valueOf(arrayInput4[a][b]);
                            String a5 = String.valueOf(arrayInput5[a][b]);
                            String a6 = String.valueOf(arrayInput6[a][b]);
                            String a7 = String.valueOf(arrayInput7[a][b]);
                            String a8 = String.valueOf(arrayInput8[a][b]);
                            arrayList.add(a1+a2+a3+a4+a5+a6+a7+a8); // Store 1110001 into ArrayList
                        }
                    }
```

Hope it could help someone else.